# NVD3 Line Chart X Axis Ticks Are Missing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, linechart

I am using NVD3 to display line chart here: http://jsbin.com/xodaxafiti/2/edit?js,output

But it seems like NVD3 auto-hide some tickLabels on XAxis, but only those ticks near the edge, i.e. 2-3Oct and 27-28Oct (except the first and last tick). I know that this is an auto-reduce because when I increase the width of chart, the ticks start to show up. However I find that this reducing behaviour weird, and the lineChart does not have reduceXTicks option like multiBarChart.

I want to be able to control the reducing behaviour myself like [this](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/70):

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart()       
   .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
   .margin({left: 80,top: 20,bottom: 120,right: 20});  

chart.xAxis.ticks(function() {
   return data[0].map(chart.x()).filter(function(d,i) {
      i % Math.ceil(data[0].values.length / (availableWidth / 100)) === 0;
   })
})
```

But it didn't work. Anyone has any idea how to control this?

[image: missing tickLabels]

Comment: Use `.tickValues()` instead of `.ticks()`.

Comment: I've tried using `.tickFormat()` before, but it gave me a filter on top of the above missing tickLabels. Besides, when using this trick, the hidden label will not even show up in tooltip. I believe `tickValues()` will have the same result.

Comment: Hmm, I would use a time scale for the x axis -- this should allow you to control better what's shown. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058876/how-do-i-display-dates-on-the-x-axis-for-nvd3-d3-js) should be helpful for that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reducing behavior works because the `showMaxMin` set to true by default. Adding `.showMaxMin(false)` fixes the problem:

```
chart.xAxis.axisLabel("XAxisLabel")
    .showMaxMin(false)    
    .tickValues(tickvalues)        
    .tickFormat(function (d) {
      return tickformat[d];
      })
;
```

[image]

Comment: watch out that you don't have any tickvalues that are out of range or they'll appear to the left of the yaxis. you can also use `xDomain` to set the extent of the xAxis

Comment: This one was messing my mind, thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have both the boundary ticks and the ticks close to the boundary(MaxMin) values, you can modify the source.

In the nv.models.axis(), there is a buffer given when showMaxMin is true for a bottom/top orientation:

```
if (showMaxMin && (axis.orient() === 'top' || axis.orient() === 'bottom')) {
            var maxMinRange = [];
            wrap.selectAll('g.nv-axisMaxMin')
                .each(function(d,i) {
                   try {
                        if (i) // i== 1, max position
                            maxMinRange.push(scale(d) - this.getBoundingClientRect().width - 4);  //assuming the max and min labels are as wide as the next tick (with an extra 4 pixels just in case)
                        else // i==0, min position
                            maxMinRange.push(scale(d) + this.getBoundingClientRect().width + 4)
                    }catch (err) {
                        if (i) // i== 1, max position
                            maxMinRange.push(scale(d) - 4);  //assuming the max and min labels are as wide as the next tick (with an extra 4 pixels just in case)
                        else // i==0, min position
                            maxMinRange.push(scale(d) + 4);
                    }
                });
            // the g's wrapping each tick
            g.selectAll('g').each(function(d, i) {
                if (scale(d) < maxMinRange[0] || scale(d) > maxMinRange[1]) {
                    if (d > 1e-10 || d < -1e-10) // accounts for minor floating point errors... though could be problematic if the scale is EXTREMELY SMALL
                        d3.select(this).remove();
                    else
                        d3.select(this).select('text').remove(); // Don't remove the ZERO line!!
                }
            });
}
```

I just removed these buffers:

```
try {
        if (i) // i== 1, max position
            maxMinRange.push(scale(d));
        else // i==0, min position
            maxMinRange.push(scale(d))
 }catch (err) {
         if (i) // i== 1, max position
              maxMinRange.push(scale(d));
         else // i==0, min position
              maxMinRange.push(scale(d));
 }
```