# nvd3 tickValues() not drawing ticks close to boundary values

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I am drawing a line chart using nvd3 and specifying a set of xAxis values to draw ticks for using:

```
chart.xAxis.tickValues(tickArr)
```

where tickArr has the list of points to draw ticks for.

For some reason, the ticks close to the beginning or the end values for the x axis are not being drawn. I am guessing this is because of some default setting for the boundary value ticks but am not able to find a way to override it and show all specified ticks.

Here is the link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arjun010/r7B9t/14/) . You can see that though tickArr has 7 data points, only 3 ticks are shown.

Any help as to which parameter should I change or why this is happening would be really appreciated.

Comment: first check your data point values,then check which scale u r using linear or log scale, share ur current code

Comment: updated the question with the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the source to get around this situation.
In the nv.models.axis(), there is a buffer given when showMaxMin is true for a bottom/top orientation:

```
if (showMaxMin && (axis.orient() === 'top' || axis.orient() === 'bottom')) {
            var maxMinRange = [];
            wrap.selectAll('g.nv-axisMaxMin')
                .each(function(d,i) {
                   try {
                        if (i) // i== 1, max position
                            maxMinRange.push(scale(d) - this.getBoundingClientRect().width - 4);  //assuming the max and min labels are as wide as the next tick (with an extra 4 pixels just in case)
                        else // i==0, min position
                            maxMinRange.push(scale(d) + this.getBoundingClientRect().width + 4)
                    }catch (err) {
                        if (i) // i== 1, max position
                            maxMinRange.push(scale(d) - 4);  //assuming the max and min labels are as wide as the next tick (with an extra 4 pixels just in case)
                        else // i==0, min position
                            maxMinRange.push(scale(d) + 4);
                    }
                });
            // the g's wrapping each tick
            g.selectAll('g').each(function(d, i) {
                if (scale(d) < maxMinRange[0] || scale(d) > maxMinRange[1]) {
                    if (d > 1e-10 || d < -1e-10) // accounts for minor floating point errors... though could be problematic if the scale is EXTREMELY SMALL
                        d3.select(this).remove();
                    else
                        d3.select(this).select('text').remove(); // Don't remove the ZERO line!!
                }
            });
}
```

I just removed these buffers:

```
try {
        if (i) // i== 1, max position
            maxMinRange.push(scale(d));
        else // i==0, min position
            maxMinRange.push(scale(d))
 }catch (err) {
         if (i) // i== 1, max position
              maxMinRange.push(scale(d));
         else // i==0, min position
              maxMinRange.push(scale(d));
 }
```

There is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624430/nvd3-line-chart-x-axis-ticks-are-missing) talking about a similar issue. The solution posted there is to remove the boundary ticks but this seems like the wrong approach as the boundary ticks are very helpful when considering the perceptual aspects of the visualization. I hope this answer helps someone who faces a similar situation in the future.