# Remove space between ticks in nvd3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

Following the question [NVD3 Line chart tics wrongly aligned to grid when using datetype on xAxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959649/nvd3-line-chart-tics-wrongly-aligned-to-grid-when-using-datetype-on-xaxis/34286098?noredirect=1#comment59675772_34286098):

In short:

> The problem I have encountered now is that my data is wrongly aligned with the Axis

**The  Problem**

When I have no data for one day (or more) the graph "save" a place for the missing day. I want to avoid it.

[image]

**I know that I can add the missing day's data with `0`s but my question is if I can do this without it.**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'lineChart',
      height: 500,
      useInteractiveGuideline: true,
      xAxis: {
        tickFormat: function(d) {
          return d3.time.format('%H %d/%m')(new Date(d));
        },
        rotateLabels: -45,
        tickValues: function(values) {
          var a =  _.map(values[0].values, function(v) {
            return new Date(v.x);
          });
          return a;
        }
      }
    }
  };


  $scope.data = [
    // date, series1, series2, series
    [1446418800000, 2, 2, 1],
    [1446505200000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1446591600000, 14, 12, 2],
    [1446678000000, 65, 38, 27],
    [1446764400000, 11, 6, 5],
    // [1446850800000, 0, 0, 0],
    // [1446937200000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447023600000, 6, 4, 2],
    [1447110000000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447196400000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447282800000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447369200000, 12, 2, 10],
    [1447455600000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447542000000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447628400000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447714800000, 1, 0, 1]
  ];

  var graphData = function(data, labels, colors) {
    var series = [];

    // first(0) value is date
    for (var i = 1; i < data[0].length; i++) {
      var values = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        values.push({
          x: data[j][0], // x is date
          y: data[j][i] // y is value
        });
      }
      series.push({
        values: values, // graph data
        key: labels[i - 1], // the label
        color: colors[i - 1] // color of series
      });
    }
    return series;
  };

  $scope.graphData = graphData($scope.data, ['One', 'Two', 'Three'], ['#6C6C6C', '#2ca02c', '#E43211']);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular-nvD3 Line Chart</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/novus/nvd3/master/build/nv.d3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.3/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
    <script data-require="lodash.js@1.3.1" data-semver="1.3.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.3.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <nvd3 options="options" data="graphData" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"></nvd3>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/42uzlu4AjnHJpI7o41l3?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@krispo](https://github.com/krispo) on [github](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/378) here is the answer:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'lineChart',
      height: 500,
      useInteractiveGuideline: true,
      x: function(d){ return d.i},
      xAxis: {
        tickFormat: function(d) {
          var data = $scope.graphData[0].values[d].x;
          return d3.time.format('%H %d/%m')(new Date(data));
        },
        rotateLabels: -45,
        tickValues: function(values) {
          var a =  _.map(values[0].values, function(v,i) {
            return i
          });
          return a;
        },
        showMaxMin: false
      }
    }
  };


  $scope.data = [
    // date, series1, series2, series
    [1446418800000, 2, 2, 1],
    [1446505200000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1446591600000, 14, 12, 2],
    [1446678000000, 65, 38, 27],
    [1446764400000, 11, 6, 5],
    // [1446850800000, 0, 0, 0],
    // [1446937200000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447023600000, 6, 4, 2],
    [1447110000000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447196400000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447282800000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447369200000, 12, 2, 10],
    [1447455600000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447542000000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447628400000, 0, 0, 0],
    [1447714800000, 1, 0, 1]
  ];

  var graphData = function(data, labels, colors) {
    var series = [];

    // first(0) value is date
    for (var i = 1; i < data[0].length; i++) {
      var values = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        values.push({
          i: j,
          x: data[j][0], // x is date
          y: data[j][i] // y is value
        });
      }
      series.push({
        values: values, // graph data
        key: labels[i - 1], // the label
        color: colors[i - 1] // color of series
      });
    }
    return series;
  };

  $scope.graphData = graphData($scope.data, ['One', 'Two', 'Three'], ['#6C6C6C', '#2ca02c', '#E43211']);
  console.log($scope.graphData);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular-nvD3 Line Chart</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>    

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/novus/nvd3/master/build/nv.d3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.3/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
    <script data-require="lodash.js@1.3.1" data-semver="1.3.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.3.1/lodash.min.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="app.js"></script>-->
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <nvd3 options="options" data="graphData" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"></nvd3>
  </body>
</html>
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/42uzlu4AjnHJpI7o41l3?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I do not have a complete answer here, but since you follow my answer from the previous question, I will describe the consequences.

The problem occurs because you provide the `tickValues` on your own. If you delete the custom function the axis will use it's default function and produce a (let's call it) evenly distributed ticks:
[image: default function ticks]

Therefore, the place you should fix is the `tickValues` function. In my opinion, adding logic to it, so it would produce evenly distributed ticks would be quite hacky, but not impossible (and I could think of couple ways to do it). But still (imo) in this situation it would be best to do it on the server side.

Good luck!