# Angular nvd3 line chart is wrongly alligned when we use DateTime as X-Axis ticks

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

I am currently working with NVD3 using Angular Directive (angular-nvd3). I have a very simple line chart with very simple data.

The problem I have encountered now is that my data is wrongly aligned with the Axis.

I am using dates on my xAxis, which are parsed using d3 library:

```
tickFormat: function(d) {return d3.time.format('%d/%m')(new Date(d))}
```

I googled lot, but wouldn't find any satisfactory answer. Please help, Thanks

Comment: can you please upload jsfiddle version of your code

Comment: running sample version is [here ](http://plnkr.co/edit/DKltsBc3esj9WTn1fdA2?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your `index.html`

`<script data-require="lodash.js@1.3.1" data-semver="1.3.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.3.1/lodash.min.js"></script>`

And you have to add additional tickValues to your xAxis

`rotateLabels: -45,
        tickValues: function(values) {
          return _.map(values[0].values, function(v) {
            return new Date(v.x);
          });
        }`

Here is [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/23n3ll?p=preview)

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959649/nvd3-line-chart-tics-wrongly-aligned-to-grid-when-using-datetype-on-xaxis) for more information. Even this looks like gives you some bugs, but looks like this is best possible solution.

Comment: I got better solution without using that library.

Comment: Check my solution here by using simple array

Comment: I have used a simple array consisting all the x-axis ticks values which i want to show on x-axis, here is my solution [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DKltsBc3esj9WTn1fdA2?p=preview) .