# NVD3 x-axis labels misaligned for lineChart and historicalChart

Tags: d3.js, charts, nvd3.js, linechart

This is similar to issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959649/nvd3-line-chart-tics-wrongly-aligned-to-grid-when-using-datetype-on-xaxis).

In this sample working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/sujit77/pp7Ljh17/), I have implemented a line chart and a historical chart.

```
chart.xAxis
    .showMaxMin(true)
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%b %d')(new Date(d)) })
```

Everything thing works as expected, except that axis lables in x-axis are not in sync with line points or the bar.

As the solution suggested in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959649/nvd3-line-chart-tics-wrongly-aligned-to-grid-when-using-datetype-on-xaxis) says that it is due to formatting of date, I have tried to format date/time in my [new example](https://jsfiddle.net/sujit77/pp7Ljh17/1/).
But the issue remains same.

```
chart.xAxis
    .showMaxMin(true)
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%b %d %Y')(new Date(d)) })
```

To me it initially looked an issue of NVD3 library cause same formatting works perfectly for other chart types I checked. Thus I raised an issue [here](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/2060).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the xScale. Do `chart.xScale(d3.time.scale())`

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect.